# How to get the position of string array in android?

Tags: android

```
String[] bike = {"Tvs","Suzuki", "Yamaha","Bajaj", "Hero","Honda", "Daivel"};
```

by clicking any one of the values, I want it to return the position of the element..

Comment: Can you elaborate your question i cannot understand what is intension

Comment: Your getting position then what is the problem as you have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for this-

```
String valueFoundOnClick="yourValue";

for(int i =0; i < bike .length; i++)
{
if(valueFoundOnClick.equals(bike[i]))
position= i;// i is the position
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly do you mean, but if you're using [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) check [getSelectedItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition()) from AdapterView

If you mean getting an item position from an array you may use this

```
Arrays.asList(array).indexOf('D');
```